# Proof verification: proof with families of sets

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

The question

Suppose $F$ and $G$ are non-empty families of sets. Prove if $F \subseteq G$, then $ \cap G \subseteq \cap F$.

My proof

Let $x$ be arbitrary element of $F$. Let $y$ be arbitrary element of $\cap G$. Assume $y \in \cap G$. This means for all arbitrary set $A$ in $G$, $y$ is element of $A$. Let $B$ be arbitrary set in $F$ and assume $B \in F$. Since $B$ is an element of $F$ and $F$ is a subset of $G$, $B$ is an element of $G$. If $y$ is element of $\cap G$, then $y$ is an element of $B$ since $B$ is element of $G$. Therefore, if $y \in \cap G$ then $y\in \cap F$, which is what $\cap G \subseteq \cap F$ means.

Is the proof accurate? What can I do to make the proof more clear?

Thank you for your time

Comment: A couple things unrelated to mathematical content: Instead of \epsilon, use \in. So you get $y\in \cap G$ rather than $y\epsilon \cap G.$ Second, at a couple points you say something like "Let $B$ be an arbitrary set in $F$ and assume $B\in F$." The second clause is redundant with the first. Just say "Let $B$ be an arbitrary set in $F$" or you can even just say "Let $B\in F$" ('arbitrary' is generally implied, and it's clear from context that it's a set, though I actually like the first phrasing better for clarity's sake).

Comment: The proof itself is correct.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, thanks for the help!